# What is the appropriate SAPI type to debug PHP web applications when configuring PHP executables in Eclipse/Xdebug?

Tags: php, eclipse, web-applications, configuration, eclipse-pdt

What is the appropriate SAPI type to debug PHP web applications when configuring PHP executables in Eclipse with PDT and Xdebug?

The available options for SAPI type under PHP executables in Eclipse PDT are CLI or CGI.

Does this depend simply on what executable is being used to debug... say when PHP.exe is defined as the executable it seems to make sense to setup PHP with SAPI type set to CLI whereas when adding the executable PHP-cgi.exe SAPI type should be set to CGI...

I followed a couple of tutorials;
http://eclipse.org/pdt/documents/XDebugGuideForPDT2.0.pdf 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-php-eclipse-pdt-debug/section4.html
eclipse.org/pdt/articles/debugger/

docs.joomla.org/Configuring_Eclipse_and_Xdebug

but i do not believe they refer to this specific issue.

In my situation PHP is running as a module in Apache. What PHP executable and SAPI type combination should be defined to best debug PHP web applications ?

Comment: @user1122069 and I followed a couple http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/documents/XDebugGuideForPDT2.0.pdf http://docs.joomla.org/Configuring_Eclipse_and_Xdebug http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/articles/debugger/os-php-eclipse-pdt-debug-pdf.pdf                   http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-php-eclipse-pdt-debug/section4.html but they do not refer to this specific issue i beleive

Comment: 'PHP Executables' settings are not necessary for web applications. It is only for running/debugging local scripts. See Help Contents(Help->PDT User Guide->Tasks->Debugging Files and Applications->Locally Debugging a PHP Script, Debugging a PHP Web Page.)(even though the contents is too much old)

Comment: @atlanto thank you for clearing this up :) much appreciated